# Not able to compile Realsense c++ project

Tags: c++, realsense

I am trying to compile a project to control the R200 Realsense camera. I have ported all necessary Realsense libraries to a local project (see [linked picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFaR1.png)) but when I try to build this c++ project I get several errors. I am sure the errors come because problems including the `rs.h` library (also local) but I cannot solve it :(

As I said, all code files are local and under the same folder:

- main.cpp
- rs.h
- rs.hpp
- rscore.hpp
- rsutil.h

Here, as an example, one the errors I am getting. The other errors are similar but referring to other functions, all of them under `rs.h`

`/home/xxx/Documents/Realsense/R200/rsutil.h:85: undefined reference to 'rs_set_device_options'`

Can anyone give me a hint how to been able to make 'rs.h' available to the rest of the code?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `rs.h` is available just fine; undefined references are _linker_ errors. You need to link with the appropriate RealSense libraries. But since you say nothing about your platform or build environment, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: You could start from [one of the examples](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/examples/hello-realsense).

Comment: Hi @Thomas, thanks for your fast response and for your first answers. Regarding the platform, I’m using Linux Mint and compiling the program with gcc. Thanks for the link to the example, however those examples are done for the newest Realsense sensors using the latest SDk but my sensor is quite old (2015)… Nevertheless I will take a look and see if I can gain some knowledge from there

Comment: Ah, right, you'll want the [v1 examples](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/v1.12.4/examples) then.